# What is meant by react-redux binding?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having trouble understanding the question and finding answers.

Is it the usage of the provider wrapper component? Or using the react-redux hooks useDispatch and useSelector? Or the concept of action - reducer - state?